# Is there any way to modify criteria of what values to allow in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of values. I want to make a second array based on the first one with stricter criteria. For example, what I want specifically is:

```
arrayOne[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]
```

How would I make it so in my new array, only the values that show up 5 times are a part of the array and only show up once. Example: `arrayTwo [1,4]`

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and have been given an opportunity to code a decision making system for one of my business courses instead of doing the final exam. Any help you can give would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: why `[1, 4]`? it is a range with 5 items?

Comment: Yes, in my actual code the numbers are names (victoria, queens, etc.) and I have  many more values. I just made them numbers to be easier to follow.

Comment: so you want only items with a count of 5 at any order?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have made that more clear

Answer (score 5):

You could use a hash table, which counts each found element and then use the count for filtering and get only the fifth element as result set in a single loop.

```js
var array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
    count = Object.create(null),
    result = array.filter(v => (count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1) === 5);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Did not think of this at all. Great solution. Taking notes :)

Answer (score 0):

I commented the code with the steps I took:

```js
const arrayOne = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5];

function method(arr, minimum) {
  //Create an object containing the amount each number occurs
  const occurrences = arr.reduce((o, n) => {
    //If number is already in the object add 1
    if (o[n]) o[n] = o[n] + 1;
    //Else set its occurence to 1
    else o[n] = 1;
    //Return the object for the next iteration
    return o;
  }, {});
  //Deduplicate the array be creating a Set(every elements can only occur once) and spread it back into an array 
  const deduplicate = [...new Set(arr)];
  //Filter array to only contain elements which have the minimum of occurences
  const filtered = deduplicate.filter(n => occurrences[n] >= minimum);
  return filtered;
}

console.log(method(arrayOne, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for this.

```
let arrayOne = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5];
let counterMap = new Map();
arrayOne.forEach(value => {
    let valueStr = value.toString();
    counterMap.set(valueStr, counterMap.has(valueStr) ? counterMap.get(valueStr) + 1 : 1);
});
let arrayTwo = [];
counterMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
    if(value >= 5) {
       arrayTwo.push(key);
    }
});
console.log(arrayTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant answer, but I assume you're looking just to find all values that appear at least 5 times.

```js
     const arrayOne = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]

     const arrayTwo = Object.entries(arrayOne.reduce((obj, num) => {
         if(!obj[num]){
          obj[num] = 1
         } else {
          obj[num] = obj[num] + 1
         }
         return obj
        }, {})).filter(([key, value]) => {
         return value >= 5
        }).map((item) => {
         return parseInt(item[0])
        })
        
        
   console.log(arrayTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5];
```

Define a function that will take an `array` and `numOfOccurrences`

```
const filterByOcur = (arr, numOfOccurrences) => {
  // create an object to act as a counter this will let us 
  // iterate over the array only once
  const counter = {};
  const res = new Set();

  for (let num of arr) {
    // if it's the first time we see the num set counter.num to 1;
    if (!counter[num]) counter[num] = 1;
    // if counter.num is greater or equal to numOfOccurrences
    // and we don't have the num in the set add it to the set
    else if (++counter[num] >= numOfOccurrences && !res.has(num)) res.add(num);
  }

  // spread the Set into an array
  return [...res];
};

console.log(
  filterByOcur(a, 5)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is number of ways of doing this, I will try to explain this step by step:

1. Array declaration

```
const a = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]
```

2. Method to count elements in an array, we are using reducer function that as a first argument takes object where key is our value from array and has a incremental number as a value. Remeber to start reducer with empty object

```
const counted = a.reduce((counter, value) => {
    if (counter[value]) counter[value]++
    else counter[value] = 1
    return counter
}, {})
```

3. Make your array unique with Set constructor

```
const uniq = Array.from(new Set(a))
```

4. Fire filter functions on the uniq array with a help of counted array, look how we access it:

```
const onlyOne = uniq.filter(val => counted[val] === 1)
const onlyFive = uniq.filter(val => counted[val] === 5)
```

5. Merge all filtered arrays into one

```
const final = [].concat(onlyOne, onlyFive)
```